# Why can I std::move a stream rvalue ref into an lvalue ref?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

As far as I understand C++11 references, I should not be able to bind an rvalue reference to a (non-const) lvalue reference as the former might be bound to a temporary and the latter must never be bound to a temporary.

However I found this odd behaviour in conjunction temporary stream objects (which I reduced as far as I could)

```
struct Dummy {};
template <typename Stream>
Stream& operator<<(Stream& s, Dummy) {
  return s << ".";          // <- (A)
}

template <typename Stream>
void pass(Stream&& s) {
  std::move(s) << Dummy();  // <- (X)   rvalue->lvalue conversion?
}

#include <fstream>
int main() {
  pass(std::fstream("test",std::ios::out));
}
```

If I write `s << Dummy()` in line `(X)`, C++ complains in line `(A)`, saying

> `error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::basic_fstream<char>&’ from expression of type ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’`

However, why does the code (as shown above) compiles *and works as expected*? The rvalue reference returned by `std::move` should just be as unable to being bound to an lvalue reference as the expression `s` is, but both `gcc 4.6.1` and `gcc 4.7.2` react identically.

And why does this phenomenon only appear to work with streams? When directly passing a `Dummy&&` to a function that expects a `T&` fails both with and without `std::move`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`basic_ostream` has an overload of `operator<<` that looks like this:

```
template <typename Elem, typename Traits, typename T>
basic_ostream<Elem, Traits>&
    operator<<(basic_ostream<Elem, Traits>&& sink, const T& val)
{
    return sink << val;
}
```

This is called "Rvalue stream insertion" in the standard, at §27.7.3.9 [ostream.rvalue].

It allows implicit conversion (of sorts) from an rvalue `basic_ostream` to an lvalue.  It was introduced specifically to allow [temporary streams to be usable without resorting to tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179522/why-does-writing-to-temporary-stream-fail).

---

As for why the compile fails when you omit the move:

When `Stream& operator<<(Stream& s, Dummy)` is called *without* the move, `Stream` will be `std::fstream` which inherits from `std::ostream` (i.e. `basic_ostream<char>`).

It will use the `basic_ostream<E, T>& operator<<(basic_ostream<E, T>&, const char*)` overload to insert your string, then try to return the result of that expression *which will be an `ostream`*. You cannot implicitly downcast from `std::ostream&` to `std::fstream&`, so you get an error.

You can fix this by returning `s` on it's own line (where it won't have been implicitly upcasted.)

This isn't a problem *with* move because you go through that rvalue-to-lvalue insertion operator we just discovered first. Inside that function, the stream is a `basic_ostream` and so `Stream` is as well, and the return types will match.

Comment: I see. That does make sense. But why is `std::move` needed at all, then?

Comment: @bitmask: Because without it `s` cannot bind to an rvalue reference, given that it is an lvalue.

Comment: @KerrekSB: But it has a perfectly good overload for an rvalue referenced stream to bind to (as shown in this answer). Why doesn't that overload match without encouragement from `std::move`?

Comment: @bitmask: That's not quite enough. Check out [this example](http://ideone.com/cDBJNy): If you remove `std::move`, it will no longer compile. (But I missed the important point about the downcast which you get because of your return type. You can try changing the operator to include a `static_cast<Stream&>`.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I simply changed the implementation of `operator<<` to return its parameter in an extra statement. It strikes me as a lot better than unnecessary casts (I don't like casts).

Comment: @GManNickG Does the conversion of the rvalue reference to an lvalue reference include any risks? I was told this "Rvalue stream insertion" pattern would cause unsolved problems and should not be used anymore, but it wasn't explained why.

Comment: @Silicomancer I am unsure. I too have heard these claims, but have not seen a concrete reason why. I'm sure it's possible this could cause problems in some sense of the word "possible" (e.g., a contrived example), but I expect this to more or less just work with typical code.